# How to swap img on JQuery toggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, toggle

I'm still a beginner in regards to JQuery, I'm trying to create a FAQ page where each outermost div contains the question and an image showing either a plus or minus to indicate whether the question is toggled open or not, when toggled open the answer shows.

I have the toggle working with multiple divs (so not every div's answer opens) but I cannot figure out how to swap the plus/minus images... any help would be appreciated

**EDIT:** im not trying to use the image as the toggle, im trying to change the drop down icon after the class has been toggled. For example, once a user clicks the faq-question-container class, the toggle works, and opens the answer container, its when the toggle works and the answer is shown that i want the q-container-img class to change from the plus icon to the minus icon

```js
$(".faq-question-container").click(function () {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
```

```css
.body .container {
        padding: 2rem 2rem 4rem;
        max-width: 1500px;
    }

    .body {
        background: url(https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-na7zipikz3/images/stencil/original/image-manager/faq-background-min.jpeg) no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
        margin: 0;
    }

    ol.breadcrumbs {
        place-content: center;
        display: flex;
    }

    .breadcrumb {
        padding: 1rem .5rem;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .breadcrumb a {
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .breadcrumb a:hover {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .breadcrumb::before {
        color: white;
    }

    .breadcrumb.is-active {
        padding: 1rem 0;
    }

    .breadcrumb.is-active>.breadcrumb-label {
        color: #4c9944;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-left: .5rem;
    }

    .page-heading {
        margin: 0 0 1rem;
        color: white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .faq-body {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        padding: 3rem 8rem;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    hr {
        margin: auto;
        width: 40%;
        border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    }

    .faq-description {
        color: white;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-style: italic;
        width: 63%;
        margin: auto;
        font-size: 13px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Open Sans";
        line-height: normal;
        margin-bottom: 5rem;
    }

    .faq-description a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .faq-subcats-icon-bkgd {
        width: 60px;
        background: rgb(255 255 255 / 65%);
        padding: 1rem;
        border-radius: 100%;
    }

    .faq-subcat-header {
        display: flex;
        gap: 1.5rem;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .faq-subcat-header h3 {
        align-self: center;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: "Open Sans";
    }

    .faq-question-container {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
        border-radius: 10px;
        color: white;
        padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 2rem;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 90% 10%;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: "Open Sans";
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .faq-question-container img {
        align-self: center;
        place-self: center;
    }

    .q-container-img {
        width: 24px;
    }

    .reveal-answer {
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: white;
        font-family: "Open Sans";
        font-weight: bolder;
        padding: 0 5rem 3rem;
        line-height: normal;
    }

    .shop-bw-btn,
    .shop-cw-btn {
        background: black;
        padding: 1rem;
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-family: 'Impact';
        font-style: normal;
    }

    .shop-bw-btn {
        color: white;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
    }

    .shop-cw-btn {
        color: #808080;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #808080;
    }

    .shop-bw-btn:hover {
        color: white;
    }

    .faq-answer-btn {
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 3rem;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-subcat-header">
    <div class="faq-subcats-icon-bkgd"><img class="faq-subcats-icon" title="Popular Topics Icon"
            src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-na7zipikz3/images/stencil/original/image-manager/popular.png"
            alt="star enclosed in a circle" /></div>
    <h3>Popular Topics</h3>
</div>
<!-- question 1 -->
<div class="faq-question-container">
    <div class="q-container-text">We use Undercoating In A Can in our shop. Are there any concerns spraying your product
        onto Chevy trucks with
        the wax based material the factory uses? Will it drip?</div>
    <img class="q-container-img" id="swapPlus"
        src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-na7zipikz3/images/stencil/original/image-manager/plus-min.png"
        alt="green plus icon" title="See the answer" />
    <img class="q-container-img" id="swapMinus" style="display: none;"
        src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-na7zipikz3/images/stencil/original/image-manager/minus-min.png"
        alt="green mius icon" title="Hide the answer" />
</div>
<div class="reveal-answer" style="display: none;">The Original Black Wax is comptabile with the hot melt dip factory wax
    applied to GM SUVs and Truck chassis. The Original Black Wax has good sag resistance but will drip if over applied.
    <div class="faq-answer-btn"><a href="/undercoating-in-a-can-black-wax-coating/" class="shop-bw-btn">SHOP ORIGINAL
            BLACK WAX</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- question 2 -->
<div class="faq-question-container">
    <div class="q-container-text">Can Original Black Wax Undercoating In A Can be applied to a wood substrate?</div>
    <img class="q-container-img" id="swapPlus"
        src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-na7zipikz3/images/stencil/original/image-manager/plus-min.png"
        alt="green plus icon" title="See the answer" />
    <img class="q-container-img" id="swapMinus" style="display: none;"
        src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-na7zipikz3/images/stencil/original/image-manager/minus-min.png"
        alt="green mius icon" title="Hide the answer" />
</div>
<div class="reveal-answer" style="display: none;">Original Black Wax and our Clear Wax are excellent sealers for wood.
    Trailer manufacturers apply the wax undercoating to the entire steel and wood undercarriage of over the road
    trailers because it seals the wood and repels mositure. Please note that th wax should be applied to the underside
    of the wood, as it is not suitable to receive pedestrian traffic.
    <div class="faq-answer-btn">
        <a href="/undercoating-in-a-can-black-wax-coating/" class="shop-bw-btn">SHOP ORIGINAL
            BLACK WAX</a>
        <a href="/undercoating-in-a-can-clear-wax-coating/" class="shop-cw-btn">SHOP CLEAR WAX</a>
    </div>
</div>
```